# Is an Oracle a Smart Contract or an EOA?

Tags: oracles

As provided in the Title, I am not clear about the concept connected to Oracles. I'm wondering if it is a Smart Contract or an EOA? Can somebody bring more clarity to the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear let's talk about an "oracle service" instead of just an oracle.

An oracle service consists of two parts: a smart contract and a backend system. When you request some data from an "oracle" you send a transaction to the oracle service's smart contract from your contract. That oracle contract emits a specific event which their backend system catches. Based on the event data the backend system knows what data to retrieve, and once it gets the data from whatever external system it submits the data to the (possibly) same oracle contract which relays the data back to your contract. The backend system is basically an EOA with attached functionality.

So an oracle can't work with either just a smart contract or just a backend system - it's a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

An Oracle is actually a combination of parts, so asking if it's one or the other isn't accurate.

1. An oracle reads off the blockchain. They can have an oracle contract (a smart contract) that they receive some token to in exchange for their oracle services. The oracle can later withdraw the tokens.
2. Oracles often also write data onto the chain, they need some form of an account to do this. Most often, we see this done with an EOA.

So it's more accurate to ask "Which does an oracle use, an EOA, or a Smart Contract" and the answer is that an oracle *can* use both. But it depends on the oracle architecture. Most often, yes, they have both parts.